# Cross-compiler Toolchain and OpenEmbedded +BeagleBoard

Tags: kernel, cross-compiling, toolchain, beagleboard

I recently start building the filesystem for Beagle Board through OpenEmbedded, but now I also want to change its kernel using the shown here: 
             http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard#Linux_kernel.

To do that I need the staging and the cross-compiler toolchain directories, but I can't find them. The top level directories that appear after doing the console-image are:

$ find tmp -maxdepth 2 -type d
tmp
tmp/work
tmp/work/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/work/i686-linux
tmp/work/beagleboard-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/work/all-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/download
tmp/download/sources
tmp/pstage
tmp/pstage/angstromglibc
tmp/pstage/pstaging_lists
tmp/rootfs
tmp/deploy
tmp/deploy/glibc
tmp/pkgdata
tmp/pkgdata/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/pkgdata/i686-linux
tmp/pkgdata/beagleboard-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/pkgdata/all-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/stamps
tmp/stamps/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/stamps/i686-linux
tmp/stamps/beagleboard-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/stamps/all-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/sysroots
tmp/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/sysroots/i686-linux
tmp/sysroots/beagleboard-angstrom-linux-gnueabi
tmp/cache
tmp/cache/glibc
tmp/usr
tmp/usr/lib

Usually the cross-compiler toolchain is in the tmp/cross directory and the staging in the /tmp/staging directory.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following directories to my PATH variable and it's working:

- tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin
- tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/armv7a/bin